# A very fundamental question about average normalized power of noise

Tags: noise

If I have a average normalized power spectrum of noise is like this
$W(f)=N_0$ while frequency is $-B$ to $B$.

Why the average normalized power is $1/4 N_0 (2B)$ insteat of $N_0 (2B)$?

Comment: kept staring at it and thought.. that makes no sense!  Remark that it is $(1/4)N_0(2B)$.  not sure if that is right though.  gotta work out the math.

Comment: Yes, I have completely no idea where is the 1/4 come form.

Comment: Well I think that if you work out the formula, it comes out to 1/4.  It will take me awhile to do it, and  I am kinda lazy now (it's 3am here... :().  To get an intuition, just look at sin(t).

Comment: Where did you get these expressions? $N_0$ is typically used to denote a flat power spectral density, in which case its units are power per Hertz of bandwidth. In that case, the total power across a bandwidth $[-B,B]$ should be $2N_0 B$.

Comment: @JasonR, averaged power is defined as $lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^T|f(t)|^2dt$. $2N_0B$ is the energy.

Comment: Energy is defined as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x(t)|^2 dt$ and, by Parseval, it is also $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |X(f)|^2 df$.

Comment: @thang: But noise is typically treated as a random process (so $f(t)$ is not known for all $t$). In that case, a power spectral density is typically used instead, which isn't just the squared magnitude of the time-domain signal's Fourier transform (although that can be used as an estimator). It's unclear what the OP is actually asking about.

Comment: @JasonR, as you can see from the formula, you don't need to know $f$ at every point in time to get the average power.  If you do, all the better.  In fact, consider for example $g=f+h$ where $h$ is nonzero only on a set of measure 0, then average power of $g$ is the same as that of f.  There is a formula that relates the power spectral density and average power.  He's trying to get a derivation of this formula.  I suggested, for simplicity to save time, just do $sin(t)$ instead of generally.  I have been meaning to derive it, but got caught up with a stupid thing called the job :p

Comment: I'm still not seeing how the total power of a signal is not equal to the integral of its power spectral density as I stated previously.

Comment: @JasonR, There is no such thing as total power.  The *total power* is the energy defined as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x(t)|^2 dt$.  power is an instantaneous unit that is a function of time.  At any time $t_0$ the power is defined as $\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T+t_0}^{T+t_0} |x(t)|^2 dt$ for very small $T$.  When $t_0$ is set to 0 and $T$ extends to infinity, that is the power averaged over the entire real space.  This is why it's sometimes called average power.  So if, by total power, you mean energy, then you are right.  It is the integral of the PSD (by Parseval).

Comment: Remark that the power definition above for very small T turns into $|x(t_0)|^2$ and is consistent with (my) intuition :p

Comment: @thang: Yes, by "total power" I did erroneously mean "average power" previously. However, what you're referring to as the PSD is in fact the energy spectral density, defined as the squared magnitude of the Fourier transform of $x(t)$. I'm talking specifically about the power spectral density as defined for a stationary (or at least wide-sense stationary) random process. The noise process that the OP was asking about is better characterized in this way, which is not in general strictly equal to $|X(f)|^2$ where $x(t)$ is some realization of the process.

Comment: @JasonR, Energy density is not a term that is used as far as I know in DSP, at least not that I've been taught.  I know that it is used for physical power systems often, though.  PSD is defined as the auto-correlation of the signal (so called $Sxx$).  Unless I am mistaken, as a consequence of the the Weiner-Khinchin theorem, it is the same as $|X(f)|^2$.  Why does generation process (stationary or not) for the signal matter here?  Does WK require non-stationary process?  Can you give example that illustrates my misuse of Weiner-Khinchin?  Admittedly, it's been awhile for me.

Comment: @thang: Yes, the Wiener-Khinchin theorem is valid only for wide-sense stationary random processes. It states that the Fourier transform of a process's autocorrelation function is its power spectral density. There is no single $|X(f)|^2$ that you can state for a random process. In order to calculate an $X(f)$, you would need a time-domain signal $x(t)$, which is just a single realization of a random process; you can only make statistical arguments (i.e. by stating its expected density) as to what its spectrum should look like.

Comment: @JasonR, you don't need $|X(f)|^2$.  That's the point.  You don't need to know what the PSD is.  You're given the average over the band given.  You're now asked to find the average power.  And my point is that there is a formula that relates the average PSD over a band to the average power.  All this time discussing I could have derived it :p

Comment: I think I finally understand what you're trying to say. I'll forego any further comment awaiting this derivation. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a filter with transfer function $H(f)$ has a noise process as input, then
the output noise power $P_{\scriptstyle{\text{out}}}$ is given by
$$P_{\scriptstyle{\text{out}}} = 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |H(f)|^2 S_x(f)\,\mathrm df
$$
where $S_x(f)$ is the power spectral density of the input noise process.
If the input process is modeled as a *white noise process*, then $S_x(f)$
is a *constant*, call it $K$ for now, and so we have that
$$P_{\scriptstyle{\text{out}}} = K
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |H(f)|^2\,\mathrm df
$$
For an ideal low-pass filter with **cutoff frequency** $B$ Hz,
$$ H_{\scriptstyle{\text{lowpass}}}(f)
= \begin{cases} 1, &-B \leq f \leq B,\\
0, & |f| > B,\end{cases}$$
we have $P_{\scriptstyle{\text{out}}} = 2KB$. More generally,
for an arbitrary linear time-invariant system with maximum
passband gain equal to $1$, the *noise-equivalent* bandwidth of the system
is *defined* as
$$B_{\scriptstyle{\text{ne}}} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |H(f)|^2\,\mathrm df$$
and so we get $P_{\scriptstyle{\text{out}}} = 2KB_{\scriptstyle{\text{ne}}}$.
Put another way, the noise-equivalent bandwidth of an ideal LPF with
cutoff $B$ Hz is just $B$ Hz.

It is *conventional* in the engineering literature to write $N_0/2$ instead
of $K$ because then the output noise power expression becomes
$N_0B_{\scriptstyle{\text{ne}}}$. The *constant of proportionality*
$N_0$, measured in watts/Hz as Jason R pointed out, is convenient
for use in ordinary language when conversing with other engineers.
If we have a filter with noise
equivalent bandwidth $B_{\scriptstyle{\text{ne}}}$, and
the thermal noise power at the input of the filter  is $N_0$ watts/Hz,
then the output noise power is $N_0B_{\scriptstyle{\text{ne}}}$.
That's the way people talk during discussions. **Nobody** will say that an ideal
lowpass filter with cutoff $B$ Hz has "bandwidth" $2B$ even though
the transfer function has value $1$ for $f \in [-B,B]$ and thus
the *support* of $H_{\scriptstyle{\text{lowpass}}}(f)$ has length
$2B$.

Turning to your question, it is *not* a good idea to write $W(f) = N_0$
for $f \in [-B,B]$, but if the paper you are reading *does* insist on this notation,
then the output power is $N_0(2B)$. If the paper says that it is
$\frac{1}{4}N_0(2B)$, then it is mistaken. Another possibility is 
that there are other conditions that are mentioned in the paper that
make $\frac{1}{4}N_0(2B)$ the correct answer, but you
have *not* included these conditions in your question. For example,
if the passband gain of the ideal LPF is $\frac{1}{2}$, then
the expression $\frac{1}{4}N_0(2B)$ for the output power
is perfectly correct.

Comment: Thanks Dilip for very clearly articulating what I was trying to say above.